# Django Channels 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I have a WebSocket with Django Channels that I'm trying to send data to the consumer once they connect.

consumers.py:

```py
class CameraOnlineConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        logger.info(f"Added {self.channel_name} channel to workflow")
        query_set = await self.get_events()
        print(query_set)
        minute_delta = timedelta(seconds=60)
        difference = query_set[0].time_stamp - query_set[1].time_stamp
        if difference <= minute_delta:
            return self.send(text_data=CameraOnline.status_code)
        else:
            return self.send(text_data=CameraOffline.status_code)

    @database_sync_to_async
    async def get_events(self):
        return PastureEvent.objects.filter(result=7).order_by('-time_stamp')[:2]
```

When starting the client WebSocket:

```js
ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/camera_online/connect/")
```

I get this error printed out in the terminal:

```
    difference = query_set[0].time_stamp - query_set[1].time_stamp
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/camera_online/connect/ [127.0.0.1:43014]
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need to return a fixed collection of rows from `get_events`. Try `return list(PastureEvent.objects. ...)`.

Comment: @VisioN casting to a list returns the same error

Comment: @VisioN Printing the queryset return this:
<coroutine object CameraOnlineConsumer.get_events at 0x7f405b321240>

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the wrong class since I'm only fetching two objects with the ORM (not heavy operation) I should use the WebsocketConsumer from the channels generic module.

```py
class CameraOnlineConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        logger.info(f"Added {self.channel_name} channel to workflow")
        query_set = self.get_events()
        minute_delta = timedelta(seconds=60)
        difference = query_set[0].time_stamp - query_set[1].time_stamp
        if difference <= minute_delta:
            return self.send(text_data=CameraOnline.default_code)
        else:
            return self.send(text_data=CameraOffline.default_code)

    def get_events(self):
        return PastureEvent.objects.filter(result=7, farm_id='1').order_by('-time_stamp')[:2]
```

Comment: okay , but how to do it using async i mean with AsyncWebsocketConsumer ??

Comment: @itjuba well, I didn't use async eventually, but when I learned about it, you should put your query in a method (like get_events)  and then use the sync_to_async decorator